Should I bind my functions that don't affect state?
I have no issue with my code, I am just asking this question for learning purposes since I am a week and a half into learning react. My question is that I bind my functions that affect/change my listValue and listAdd state, so should I be binding my functions that don't affect my states like addList() and clearList() too or should I bind only when states are involved? Also, if you have any tips for optimization or something I could of done differently that makes it easier, I will gladly hear those out.


function ListApp() {
  return <List/>
}

class List extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listValue: '',
      listAdd: ''
    }

    this.handleList = this.handleList.bind(this);
    this.addValue = this.addValue.bind(this);
  }

  handleList(){
    if(this.state.listValue !== ''){
      this.setState({
        listAdd: this.state.listValue
      }, ()=>this.addList(this.state.listAdd))
    }
    document.querySelector(".textArea").value = '';
    this.setState({
      listValue: ''
    })
  }

  addValue(event){
    this.setState({
      listValue: event.target.value
    })
  }

  addList(value){
    const node = document.createElement("li");
    const textnode = document.createTextNode(value);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.querySelector(".listBox").appendChild(node);
  }

  clearList(){
    while (document.querySelector(".listBox").firstChild) { 
      document.querySelector(".listBox").firstChild.remove(); 
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="box1">
        <textarea placeholder="Type here" className="textArea" maxLength={68} onChange={this.addValue}></textarea>
        <button className="add" onClick={this.handleList}>Add</button>
        <button className="clear" onClick={this.clearList}>Clear</button>
        <ul className="listBox"></ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}




It's not about state, it's about this. If the function uses this and it gets called with no context, you need to bind it or use an arrow function. Otherwise, you do not. Btw, this is very sketchy react code: you should almost never directly modify the dom. Where did you get this from?

I made it myself for a project... I see what you mean by it referring to "this" and not the state. I had always been confused on what "this" was used for but this cleared up a bit of my confusion.

Technically, for your example it is enough to bind the functions that refer to this.state and this.setState(), BUT you misunderstood the reason for that:
You need to bind the functions that use this, because this always refers the the current execution context, and you need the functions to be executed in the context of the List component, in order to refer to the components methods / properties via the this keyword.
But with the assignment to the onClick property, the relation to the List component "gets lost".
About execution context
The exact same function could be executed in different execution contexts. E.g. consider this example:
const o = {
  fnct: function(){      // assign an anonymous function to `o.fnct`
    console.log( this ); // print current execution context
  }
};

const f = o.fnct; // assign the same function to `f` 

o.fnct();  // call the function in the context of `o`
f();       // call the function in the global context (`window` in the browser)

You get different outputs for this: the object o for o.fnct(), the global object for f().
If you need to keep the function being always executed in the context of o (instead of the current context), you need to bind the function to o:
const fTemp = o.fnct;  // this is the "plain" original function again
const fBoundToO = ftemp.bind(o); // this is the function bound to `o`
o.fnct = fBoundToO;    // re-assign the bound function to `o.fnct`

The same can be written shorter:
o.fnct = o.fnct.bind(o);

Now you can use this bound function in other contexts, but its this would still be o:
const f = o.fnct;  // assign the bound function to `f`
f();               // call `f()` in the global context, but inside `f` the bound context `o` is used

Now the object o is printed as execution context in both cases.
React onClick
When you assign the onClick={ onClickHandler } property in React, then the same as above happens:
this.onClickHandler = function(){}; // assign a function to the property `this.onClickHandler`
// ...
{
  onClick: this.onClickHandler // assign the _same_ function to `onClick`
}
// ...
List.onClickHandler();  // `this` inside the function is the List
Button.onClick();       // `this` inside the function is the Button

When onClick() is executed, it simply executes that function in whatever context it is (e.g. the button React element).
But if onClickHandler was bound to the List component (this.onClickHandler = this.onClickHandler.bind(this)), then it keeps using the List component as context (i.e. this points to the List component, and this.state is 'theListComponentInstance.state`).
Conclusion
You don't need to bind addList() and clearList() right now, because they don't use this, so it doesn't matter in which context they are executed.
But addList() and clearList() will probably cause other errors sooner or later, because they manipulate the DOM, which you should never do in React.

Thank you for clearing up the "This" misunderstanding. By manipulating the DOM in my code, you mean how it creates and deletes elements right? If you have the time, could you possibly explain why I should never manipulate the DOM? I don't seem to understand why its treated like a cardinal sin lol

Yes, basically everything that involves using the document interface should be voided. - It's not a sin, you can do that, but then your code probably won't work as you expect ;) Basically, react doesn't take notice of your changes if you use the DOM directly instead of using Reacts methods. Maybe have a look at Best practices for DOM manipulation with refs
